# if I select nodes from an XDocument is the order always preserved?

Tags: linq, linq-to-xml

Let's say I have nodes like so:

```
<Params>
 <Param val="C" />
 <Param val="D" />
 <Param val="A" />
 <Param val="B" />
<Params>
```

If I select the Descendants of Params is the order *always* preserved? I want C to always be first when I iterate through the ordered list that I'll be dropping these into. Or do I need to come up with a different solution for ordering nodes? I'd like to stay away from numbers (order="1", 2 etc.) so any suggestions would be great.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xelement.descendants.aspx) for the `Descendants` property says:

> Returns a collection of the descendant elements for this document or element, **in document order.**

So the answer is yes, they will be returned in the same order they appear in the original XML.

Comment: Oops, I spose I coulda found that. Thanks tho.